# export excel file in php with utf-8 unicode

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, export

I want to export mysql with Php (CodeIgniter) in excel format, but I have problem with UFT-8 characters. it shows the UTF-8 characters ugly.

It is my code

```
class Excel extends CI_controller{

function index(){

    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $data = $this->user_model->profile_detail_excel();  

      function cleanData(&$str)
      {
        $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
        $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
        if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
        $str = chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding( $str, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');           
        }

      // filename for download
      $filename = "website_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;  charset=UTF-16LE");


      $flag = false;
      foreach($data as $row) {
        if(!$flag) {
          // display field/column names as first row
          echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
          $flag = true;
        }
        array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
      }
      exit;


}
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: How about changing the charset=UTF-16LE to utf-8 in the headers?

Comment: I Tried UTF-8 too. not work. excel doesn't support UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use PHPExcel plugin for codeigniter. it works perfect for utf-8

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will answer the UTF-8 problem. But here is an elegant way to create CSV files with CodeIgniter - use `$this->dbutil->csv_from_result($db_result);` [Documentation Here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html#export-a-query-result-as-a-csv-file)

**Model:**

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent :: __construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->dbutil();
  }

  function profile_detail_excel($condition)
  {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('profile_table', $condition);
    if($query->num_rows() === 0)
    {
      return NULL;
    }
    //Here's the meat
    $csv = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);
    // csv_from_result accepts additional params allowing you
    // to set the delimiter, newline and enclosure characters

    //if you want to try conveting the encoding do it now
    //$csv = mb_convert_encoding( $csv, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'); 

    return $csv;
  }

}
```

Note it returns a CSV string of the whole profile.

**Controller:**

```
class Xl_xport extends CI_Controller
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_model');
  }

  function index()
  {
    $csv = $this->user_model->profile_detail_excel();
    if(!empty($csv))
    {
      // Strongly recommend using file type .csv because
      // certain versions of Excel complain about .xls that isn't really .xls
      $filename = "website_data_".date('Ymd').".csv";
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
      header("Content-Type: text/csv");

      echo $csv;
    }
    else
    {
      //you may want to handle this some other way
      throw new Exception("No Profile Found");
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks DFriend, I will test and I'll tell you the result

Comment: It does not work. I use PHPExcel plugin for codeigniter